# Class diagram - how to document echo

Tags: php, uml, class-diagram

Can i draw a UML class diagram that some how explain that my function do not return value, but rather echo it?

Here is an pseudoísh example of what my class looks like:

```
class api {
  private $data;

  public function dosomething() {
    $data = $this->getDataFromDatabase();
    echo json_encode($data);
  }

  private function getDataFromDatabase() {
    ....
  }

}
```

Here is a class diagram that shows my class above.

```
-----------------------------------
            api
-----------------------------------
    - data : string
-----------------------------------
    + dosomething() : void
    - getDataFromDatabase() : array
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: You can either use `: void` or leave it away to show that it does not return anything. So the above is ok.

Comment: Great, i had a feeling that it was the case. Could you please make an answer so i can close this question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use `: void` or leave it away to show that it does not return anything. So the above is ok and alternatively you could write

```
-----------------------------------
            api
-----------------------------------
    - data : string
-----------------------------------
    + dosomething()
    - getDataFromDatabase() : array
-----------------------------------
```